# Multi Module App doesn't reflect changes from base Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, module, multi-module

I'm building a sample multi module app where I have 1 library common, which has a MainActivity and a simple TextView. The TextView has no text defined in the xml and the MainActivity has `binding.tvText.text = getString(R.string.url)`.

I have 2 modules google and facebook, where there is no Activity, their manifests include:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.common.WebViewActivity"
          android:exported="true">
```

and I have listed the library common as a dependency for both modules (implementation project(path: ':common')). The TextView appears blank, when it should show either [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com), but what's interesting is that if I set the xml's text to `@string/url`, it works perfectly for both modules. Even changes like textColor aren't reflected in the MainActivity!

This is an issue as I want to load a WebView in the Activity with a different url for each module, but none of the changes are picked up. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Each module has it's own `R` resources class that references the resources in that same module. When you use `R.string.url` in your runtime code, it is explicitly pulling the `com.mybasemodulepackage.R.string.url` resource, not some resource that might be defined in some other module.

When you use `@string/url` in your XML, the layout inflator pulls the resource from the closest resource scope, the one from the package name that the app was built with.

I'm not sure of the best solution, if setting it in XML is not appropriate for your situation. You might have this common activity acquire the URL from the extras passed to it. Then each module can pass the URL when they open the activity.